# Delete a DIRECTORY if Disc space is under X-GIG AND more than X Days since Created! C# /NET

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

Like the topic says, here's my code.

```
public void deleteOldShit()
{
String path = textBox1.Text ;
Int32 days = Convert.ToInt32(oldRelease.Text);
Int32 neededSpace = Convert.ToInt32(discSpace.Text);
String[] folders = Directory.GetDirectories(path, "*".ToString(), SearchOption.AllDirectories);

foreach (String folder in folders)
{

    DirectoryInfo source = new DirectoryInfo(folder);
    String k = Directory.GetDirectoryRoot(path);
    k = k.Replace(@":\", "");
    DriveInfo c = new DriveInfo(k);
    Double cAvailableSpace = c.AvailableFreeSpace / Math.Pow(1024, 2);


    // Get info of each file into the directory
    foreach (DirectoryInfo fi in source.GetDirectories())
    {
        var creationTime = fi.CreationTime;

        if (creationTime < (DateTime.Now - new TimeSpan(days, 0, 0, 0)))
        {
            if (cAvailableSpace < neededSpace)
            {
                    Directory.Delete(folder,true);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Been looking at delete files after x days, but the comparison of date / time seems to be the bug.

Any pointers here would be cool. I can't seem to find an answer to this.

Comment: Could you inform us what you expect when you run this, and what happens instead?

Comment: it runs, nothing more.it scans the folders and i can see em go trough a listbox when i tested..but folders older than X days still in my folder. im runing administrator mode as well

Comment: What version of the Net Framework are you running?

Comment: Warning: File timestamps are extremely unreliable. My computer says I have a few files from the 1960's or 1600's, cant remember which.

Comment: Should the Directory.Delete use  FI.FullName, rather than Folder?

Comment: iv tested the dates on folders..says correct when try message them out.      if (creationTime < (DateTime.Now - new TimeSpan(3, 0, 0, 0)))    i need an alternative here.

Comment: folder is path to directory thats gona be deleted

Answer (score 1):

My guess is this line isn't working how you expect:

```
if (creationTime < (DateTime.Now - new TimeSpan(90, 0, 0, 0)))
```

That line is preventing folder deletion unless the folder was created more than 90 days ago. Also, the actual "X days" code seems to be wrong, as well (though it's probably not being reached)

```
if (fi.CreationTime < DateTime.Now.AddDays(days))
```

If that code was ever reached, it would *always* delete your files, unless you created them in the future, or typed a negative number in your box.

---

You have some other troubles here, though. Once you start deleting directories, you will hit Exceptions for two reasons I can see right away.

1. You aren't checking that sub-directories still exist once you have deleted their containing directory. If you delete `c:\myFiles` and then your code next checks `c:\myFiles\other`, you will have errors because your code will try to check properties on a directory that does not exist. You should check `Directory.Exists()` first.
2. Your directory delete code won't work unless the directories are empty. There is a second `bool` parameter which you need to pass `true` to in order to have it delete files and folders that are contained therein.

---

finally, just to be sure to mention; your code doesn't really check to make sure you haven't entered a dangerous directory, so be careful with this! :)

Comment: did an updated, and corrected i guess your right about that, but i dont get crashers here either atm. so somthing where it actully try find date diffeence thats the main issiue i supose?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are attempting to delete the wrong directory:

```
    foreach (String folder in folders)
    {

        DirectoryInfo source = new DirectoryInfo(folder);
        String k = Directory.GetDirectoryRoot(path);
        k = k.Replace(@":\", "");
        DriveInfo c = new DriveInfo(k);
        Double cAvailableSpace = c.AvailableFreeSpace / Math.Pow(1024, 2);


        // Get info of each file into the directory
        foreach (DirectoryInfo fi in source.GetDirectories())
        {
            var creationTime = fi.CreationTime;

            if (creationTime < (DateTime.Now - new TimeSpan(days, 0, 0, 0)))
            {
                if (cAvailableSpace < neededSpace)
                {
                        **/* Trying to delete Folder, but should be FI.Fullname */**

                    try
                       {
                        Directory.Delete(folder,true);
                       }
                    catch(Exception e)
                       {
Console.WriteLine("The process failed: {0}", e.ToString());
                       }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: But you take the folder name, and then execute GetDirectories() on the folder.   You code loops through the directories in the folder and if anyone of them meets your condition, attempts to delete the parent folder...   Not sure if that is your intent or not.

Comment: if (creationTime < (DateTime.Now - new TimeSpan(days, 0, 0, 0)))
seam that nothing get printed out after this line. my folders are over 1 week old..

Comment: try adding the indicated Try Catch block and see if an error comes back on the Directory.Delete() command   It might be attempting the delete, but failing for some reason

Comment: Are you sure you getting to the creationTime line?   I am not sure what GetDirectories() returns if you don't pass it a parameter..